# Microsoft.ML --version 0.3.0 -- Unable to Get started with ML.NET in 10 minutes

Tags: ml.net

I have follow the steps provide in (https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/apps/machine-learning-and-ai/ml-dotnet/get-started/windows) to get started with ML.NET in 10 minutes.

**But on running the app. Console is through below runtime error.**

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.FormatException: Parsing failed with an exception: Stream reading encountered exception ---> System.FormatException: Stream reading encountered exception ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\XXXX\MLNetExampleA\iris-data.txt'.
   at System.IO.FileStream.OpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.SimpleFileHandle.OpenReadStream()
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Data.FileHandleSource.OpenTextReader(Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Data.TextLoader.Cursor.LineReader.ThreadProc()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Data.TextLoader.Cursor.LineReader.GetBatch()
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Data.TextLoader.Cursor.ParallelState.Parse(Int32 tid)
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Data.TextLoader.Cursor.ParallelState.ThreadProc(Object obj)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Data.TextLoader.Cursor.<ParseParallel>d__33.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Data.TextLoader.Cursor.MoveNextCore()
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Data.RootCursorBase.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Data.TermTransform.Train(IHostEnvironment env, IChannel ch, ColInfo[] infos, ArgumentsBase args, ColumnBase[] column, IDataView trainingData)
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Data.TermTransform..ctor(ArgumentsBase args, ColumnBase[] column, IHostEnvironment env, IDataView input)
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Data.TermTransform..ctor(IHostEnvironment env, Arguments args, IDataView input)
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Transforms.TextAnalytics.TermTransform(IHostEnvironment env, Arguments input)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.EntryPoints.EntryPointNode.Run()
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.EntryPoints.EntryPointGraph.RunNode(EntryPointNode node)
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.EntryPoints.JsonUtils.GraphRunner.RunAllNonMacros()
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.EntryPoints.JsonUtils.GraphRunner.RunAll()
   at Microsoft.ML.LearningPipeline.Train[TInput,TOutput]()
   at MLNetExampleA.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\XXXX\MLNetExampleA\Program.cs:line 70
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error indicates

```
Could not find file 'C:\XXXX\MLNetExampleA\iris-data.txt'
```

Have you followed [image: this step]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](https://www.microsoft.com/net/images/redesign/learn/apps/ml-dotnet/copy-to-output-directory.png?v=qdHBK8Jkf44W9fOz8hJQcFRQH88H68F_UdyelE62x9U))</sub>
 and verified that the file is actually copied to the output folder?